# Stop a redis container from another container in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, signals

I have two containers within a pod, one is a redis server and the other connects to the redis and does some operations. Both are configured in a cronjob (not a deployment config). The processing runs successfully, but my qn is how to shutdown the redis container? In the openshift template, history limits are as below.

```
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
```

But the successfull job is not getting removed since the redis container inside it is still running. How do I signal a shutdown from the application container to the redis container?